# Laravel unique ruleset ignores the current user id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on updating a user in Laravel, where I made the following validation rule for updating a users email:

```
    "email" => "required|email|unique:users,email,".$this->route("user")->id,
```

This is inside of my form request.
However, when I post, it still says that the email is already taken? Is this perhaps a bug in the latest version of Laravel?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown us what route you are using to access this validation, but if it is something like `users/{user}`, then the user ID available in the form request is actually `$this->route("user")`, not `$this->route("user")->id`.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a bug, you are using a `null` value for the id hence the reason why, change your rule to this:

```
"email" => "required|email|unique:users,email,".$this->user()->id,
```

Make sure that you have `Request $request` in your method, and also you have the auth middleware on your controller.

Comment: My mistake, the rule is in a form request! I should have specified! Sorry

Comment: `dd($this->route("user")->id)` reveals the correct value though?

Answer (score 0):

you set the ignore email column so you should pass email not id

```
"email" => "required|email|unique:users,email,".$this->route("user")->email,
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add rules in user model

```
static function rules() {
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ];
}
```

In user controller

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule; // add this one

function add_update_user(Request $request,$user_id) {
   $data = $request->all();
    unset($data['_token']);

    $rules = User::rules();
    $rules['email'] = explode('|', $rules['email']);
    if (isset($user_id))  // is old user, your get user_id in route
    {
       $rules['unique_code'][] = Rule::unique('databse_connection_name.users')->ignore($data['email'], 'email');
    } else  // is new user
    {
        $rules['email'][] = 'unique:databse_connection_name.users,email';
    }
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    ...
    ...
}
```